# Why doesn't Shift + Cmd + M work in Eclipse the first time?

Tags: eclipse

In my IDE, I have to first navigate to the option using mouse.  Once I minimize or maximize the editor window once, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> starts working but not before that.  Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange. Would you check which command is binded to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>? Default shortcut for toggling maximize active view/editor is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. You can check this in `Preferences > General > Keys` or hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> twice.

Comment: By default Cmd+Shift+M is mapped to both add-import and maximize parts (there is a binding conflict).  I unbound Cmd+Shift+M from "maximize parts" now.  Ctrl+M works like a breeze.  Thanks.